# Как заполнить вектор при инициализации значениями в одну строку?

Tags: stl, vector, синтаксис, c++

Как заполнить вектор при инициализации значениями в одну строку? В примерах встречаю такое, а на практике не работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 }; // как заполнить вектор значениями в одну строку?

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1>d:\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\vect\vect\main.cpp(7): error C2601: v: недопустимые локальные определения функций
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да так и заполнять, как в вашем примере. Только чтоб это работало, нужен компилятор с поддержкой C++11. По всей вероятности, у вас не такой.

Вот пример:

[С++11 - работает](http://ideone.com/gAnkyH)

[С++03 - не работает](http://ideone.com/kONp7L)

Comment: Значит, буду по старинке пока.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010, насколько я помню, была не очень продвинута в плане новых фич C++. Переходите на VS 2013, она [поддерживает](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializing-classes-and-structs-without-constructors-cpp?view=msvc-170).

Вот список поддерживаемых фич [до версии 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh567368%28v=vs.140%29) включительно и [свежем preview VS 2015](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-preview/) (сгруппированно по стандартам аж до C++17).

Comment: Выше 2010 студии на windows xp не поставишь. Комп слабый.

Comment: тогда к вашим услугам другие компиляторы (и IDE соответственно)